# PHP MYSQL header() location

Tags: php, mysql, header, http-headers

I have a class that inserts users into a database, although I'm having a little trouble initialising header() re-direct. Here is my code

```
    public function Register() {

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (username, password, admin) VALUES ('$username', '$password', '0')");
    header('Location: /view_registered.php?register=success');



}
```

Is there a way I can put the header within a variable then once the method's complete adding users to the db then pass the header variable back to my index.php page?

kind regards

Answer (score 3):

Try adding a .

```
header('Location: ./view_registered.php?register=success');
```

If in a folder below

```
header('Location: ./../view_registered.php?register=success');
```

If in a folder above

```
header('Location: ./FOLDER_NAME_HERE/view_registered.php?register=success');
```

If in a different place altogether

```
header('Location: http://www.google.com');
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, although didn't work. I'm running it on a localhost at the moment. the class is loaded in an includes folder. If that helps & I've also used headers on other pages which seemed to work fine, although that was loaded from the parent dir.

Comment: If view_registered is the in the same folder it should work.  Are you sure it's executing?

Comment: They're in different folders.

my class is in an includes folder, view_registered is in it's root & I'm also calling the method from inside the body

Answer (score 0):

```
if($query)
header('Location: /view_registered.php?register=success');
```

Answer (score 0):

use [mysql_affected_rows()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php)

```
$query = '';
if(mysql_affected_rows) {
header();
exit();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help although now I just get a 'This webpage has a redirect loop'

Answer (score 0):

What trouble? May be you need to use output buffering ( http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php )?